# Display a live server time in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datetime

I am fairly new to JSP and I have been asked to produce a JSP page which displays a live server time.

Originally I was planning to use JSTL tags but of course I have discovered that JTSL tags cannot be made dynamic. So I have turned to JS code.

In my JSP page I am importing the 'java.util.Date' class, and I have defined the following jQuery library

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">

    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

</script>
```

I then have this jQuery function at the end of the page:

```
    bbTime = new java.util.Date();

    // function to display the live server date and time

    function updateTime() {

    /// Increment serverTime by 1 second and update the html for '#time'

    serverTime = new Date(bbTime.getTime() + 1000);

    jq('#time').html(serverTime.toUTCString());

    }

    jq(function() {
        updateTime();
        setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    })
```

Within the HTML section I then have this statement:

```
<div><p>Server Time:<span id="time"></span></p></div>
```

But the jQuery is not working. I just get the Server Time: section displayed and no date or time.

Is it possible ask someone to shed some light to help 
me understand where I have made my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Check browser console for errors - are there any? Hint: think about where and **when** which (JSP/Javascript) code is executed.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thank you for your advice. I ended up achieving the desired result using  a javascript function instead of jQuery. I think I need a clearer understanding of how jQuery affects the DOM. The site this code  sits on is quite complex and has a number of other js and jquery libraries being called.